# Can users of my website discover this webaddress?

Tags: php

On my website I have a function where people can sign up for a newsletter by putting in an email address. I take the email address in php, verify it's integrity and then fwrite it to a txt file, e.g. emailaddresses.txt. I noticed that if I browse to www.mywebsite.com/emailaddresses.txt the email addresses can be seen. I setup a htaccess file with Options -indexes in it.

If emailaddresses.txt is an obscure file name, very long and with random characters is that secure for the time being?

Comment: It would be much better if you just moved it out of the public folder.

Comment: How do I modify my code to do that? here is the relevant line of my php code: fwrite(fopen(emaillist.txt, 'a+'), $delimiter . $email)

Comment: you just give it a path that is outside of your webroot and then modify the path appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

[Security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) **IS NOT** secure.

Place your emailaddresses.txt outside your webroot.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. What do you mean by 'outside the webroot'? This is the relevant line of my php code: fwrite(fopen(emaillist.txt, 'a+'), $delimiter . $email)

Answer (score 2):

You can fwrite it into a location that is not accessible to your web server - that would be more secure

Answer (score 1):

**No** - you need to categorically prevent your server from serving the file, or even better write it to a location outside of the servers' scope.  Your htaccess file is likely to be faulty.  You should probably upload the appropriate section to be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

The -indexes just stops the server from listing the files when the user goes to a directory with no index file.

If you want to write to a file make sure it's outside the web root. Then you will be able to access it, but your users will never be able to see it.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. What do you mean by 'outside the webroot'? This is the relevant line of my php code: fwrite(fopen(emaillist.txt, 'a+'), $delimiter . $email);

Answer (score 0):

if you store such data in a file, put access restrictions into place that deny access to that file for unauthorized users ...

Comment: How do I accomplish this? Please advise

Comment: the obvious way: place the file outside of the web-accessible path.  if it has to be in the web-accessible path, you could use htaccess to restrict the access, for instance by this rule  <Files yourFileName>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, write it outside of your webroot (ie not accessible to the public).

Try this: `fwrite(fopen('../emaillist.txt', 'a+'), $delimiter . $email);` (note the `../` preceding emaillist.txt). This will write the email file ONE directory above your webroot, ie instead of `/home/user/public_html/emaillist.txt`, it will be located in `/home/user/emaillist.txt` - which won't be accessible via the web, but you will be able to see it via FTP.